# How to get the XML in Java spring controller

Tags: java, xml, spring, spring-boot

There is a controller like

```
public Response doSomething(@RequestBody SomeObject someObject) {
...
}
```

It gets an XML and converts it to SomeObject. What I want to know how can we can get the xml as well[preferably as string]. Xml gets printed in debug logs, but how to get it as string in program.

Comment: Just use a `String` as the type.

Comment: I require both SomeObject and String xml

Comment: You cannot. Also why would you need both, what is the use case.

Comment: XML have a very complex structure as Java object around 200 classes. I need to process whole object. Second I only need to process 40 selected fields so rather than traversing these 20 fields I can directly get them using string processing on XML.

Comment: Then again, why do you need both... Or use a different mapping library that maps the XML to an object of your choice that you can use.

Comment: Use case is for one purpose I need to process whole object second is to create checksum using only 20 field. Traversing java object tree is not easy.

Comment: And why would it be easy in XML (if you are using JAXB your java objects represent your XML one-on-one).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could serialize your object again back to xml. Here is an [example](http://www.baeldung.com/jackson-xml-serialization-and-deserialization) on how to do that.

Comment: Since we are getting the xml in first place is there a way other than unmarshaling the object.

Comment: If you want to have both POJO and XML String, I believe the best option is to unmarshal the object again. The request body can be read only once and is already read to create the object in your controller's method. There are tricks to go around that, but would only make the solution more complicated

Comment: @SaurabhPrajapati glad to hear that :) Can you accept the answer then?

Comment: I used unmarshalling but not by Jackson, I was using the JAXB for marshaling XML to SomeObject. So I used JAXB unmarshalling as well.